Surface polution post-apocalytic world
I am writing a book about a post-apocalyptic world. The surface is completely destroyed and mankind survived underground. Soon, great technological cities were built, but they still rely on items found on the surface.
This is where we meet the Main Character who somehow gets himself on a shuttle headed to the surface which ends up crashing and the main character is lost on the corrosive surface. He will end up finding other survivors on the surface and more. I don't want to spoil the ending.
What I want to know is, or looking for ideas on is: what are some of the corrosive, environmental factors he might end up facing on the surface. I am thinking of the following:

Radiation from nuclear disasters
Harmful UV rays from the sun since the atmosphere was ruined during the war.
Mutation-induced monsters
Dangerous climates and unpredictable yet ruthless weather changes.

I am hoping for something justified by science and easily explained as post-apocalyptic.

What is a crashable shuttle which goes from underground to ground level? If something like an elevator were to crash it would of course crash down to the underground. (And the main problem with justified by science is that as far as science and technology go, it is a thousand times easier to build a protected habitation space on the ground than underground, no matter how bad the climate or the ultraviolet radiation or whatever is. Building large structures underground is fiendishly hard.)

There's a lot I've left out as it is still a developing novel, but the idea is, the story begins several centuries after calamity. No one knows exactly what happened, and they all live underground.
Eventually, I want to show that there was a lot more to the story than met the surface, including an alien invasion where the aliens never left.

This seems to be fishing for plot points rather than asking a specific question with a constrained range of answers, and worldbuilding.SE isn't really the right site for that kind of thing. Do you have any specific requirements or situations in mind? Pick one that's problematic, and ask a question around that. It'll work much better than "list all the things that could be bad in a post-apocalypse".

VTC:Needs More Focus. SE is designed to help people solve one specific problem. This is brainstorming for the proverbial (and off-topic) infinite list of things. And, as usual, we're asking for "science based" answer to fanciful questions (mutation-induced monsters?) Research is expected on Stack Exchange and from a science standpoint you have basically one option: nuclear winter. From a fantasy standpoint research the game Gamma World or the entire Fallout game series (and more!).

BTW, science is your biggest problem. In Real Life (aka, science), most radiation is soon gone (in the course of a handful of years), radiation-induced mutation kills life rather than creates monsters, dust due to the nuclear winter will block pretty much all UV (and by the time the dust settles the atmosphere will be fine - The Matrix was fantasy, too) and dangerous and unpredictable weather changes won't exist. The only way to have a fun post-apocalypse story is to throw science to the wind... unless you're just writing about people overcoming starvation.

The idea is that, ultimately, when aliens invaded, they destroyed the earth's atmosphere, making the surface unlivable to most. Those that did survive on the surface had to have undergone extreme changes.
Think combination of the 100 and Shannara Chronicles

You already seem to have hit several of the dangers, but here's a few more:
It's the worst Ice Age ever - Nuclear war is predicted to cause a new Ice Age and is also how much of the world would be irradiated.
No food - There's not likely to be much safe to eat.
Animals - Mutation-induced monsters are very iffy, it might be safer to just go with normal wildlife, as normal animals can be scary enough especially if they are a bit bigger than now due to the cold and very interested in a free meal(Of course, if you don't care about that, go for it!).
As others have already pointed out, there may be a few details that need to be worked out, but this seems interesting!

Nice, I like this idea. Normal wildlife is scary but with slight mutation.
